# Are there languages with other spatial deixis besides "here", "there" and "over there"?

Tags: linguistic-typology, list-of-languages, deixis

When it comes to spatial deixis most languages seem to have either two or three distinctions:

```
2        | 3
English  | Spanish      Japanese
--------------------------------
here     | aquí / acá   koko
there    | ahí          soko
(yonder) | allá / allí  asoko
```

Are there any languages with distinctions other than these?

Comment: I've heard that Danish has a system as complex as Malagasy, but I don't speak the language myself, so you should probably ask around.

Comment: It should be noted that in Spanish, the three grades of proximity correlate precisely with the three grammatical persons. 1ˢᵗ: ‘esta cosa aquí = cerca de mí’; 2ⁿᵈ ‘esa cosa ahí = cerca de ti’; 3ʳᵈ: ‘aquella cosa allí = cerca de él’. An related question is whether other languages with three grades also have three grades in demonstratives and location-words that correspond to the three numeric persons. It might also be interesting if anyone can report on whether and how this relates to Navajo’s so-called ‘4ᵗʰ person’.

Comment: @tchrist you forget *acullá* which adds a fourth level in Spanish (and really, *aquí* is right here, whereas *acá* is in this general area here [ditto for *allí/allá*], so strictly speaking, Spanish has a six level distinction: *aquí, acá, ahí, allí, allá, acullá*.  I'm really interested in this article on *acullí* that's to be published online next year http://bulletinhispanique.revues.org/2176?lang=es ).  Also @ OP, English has threeway: *here, there, yonder* ('round these parts we still use it)

Comment: @guifa The *-á* versions are indeed less a discrete point than the *-í* versions.

Comment: @tchrist ping, that article I mentioned is now published, will probably be of interest to you.  Haven't had the time to read it in full myself though because my (lack of) French does not lend itself to quick reads.

Comment: @guifa Thanks, I'll give it a read! (My French is reasonably decent.)

Comment: Re: Japanese, there are gradations.  Adding the generalizing suffix ～ら (_-ra_) might be vaguely similar to the Spanish _-á_ versions.  There are also the inherently less specific directional / locative terms こち(ら) (_kochi[ra]_), そち(ら) (_sochi[ra]_), あち(ら) (_achi[ra]_), which as noted can optionally take the same ～ら (_-ra_) suffix.  I think in any conversational context, there are inevitably three basic "locations" -- 1) close to the speaker, 2) close to the listener, 3) not close to either.  I suspect you'll find a similar breakdown in many (most?) languages.

Comment: @PhilipSeyfi Only ten years late, but no, the Danish deixis system only distinguishes proximal (‘here’) and distal (‘there’). There is an overtly distal form (_hin_, equivalent to ‘yon’), but like ‘yon’ in English, it’s very archaic except in the fixed phrase _hinanden_ ‘each other’.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The [Malagasy language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malagasy_language) for example, national language of Madagascar, has a complex system of deixis with seven degrees of distance. Here's the tab taken from the Deixis section:

> [image] <sup>([Image Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malagasy_language#Deixis))</sup>
>
> <sup>Notes: **(1)** Diacritics in deixis are not mandatory in Malagasy; **(2)** Deixis marked by a * are rarely used.</sup>

About the Malagasy deixis, you could read *"[The Austronesian languages of Asia and Madagascar](http://books.google.it/books?id=5i1aMcmLWlMC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)"* by K. Alexander Adelaar and Nikolaus Himmelmann (see page 470).

It seems that also the Dyirbal language (Australian family; North Queensland) has 15 suffixes that attach to demonstratives or to the noun classifiers, using a system that takes into consideration:

- the *distance* (short, medium, distant);
- the *counter-current direction*;
- the *current direction of the river*;
- the *direction towards the top or base of a hill*;
- the *vertical movement towards the bottom or the top*.

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything schematic about this one yet. But you can find more about it and others in [this page](http://www.hum.uit.no/mra/SemSumms/V06/March14.htm).

Comment: Go ahead with the screenshot, people post them on other SE sites all the time. Crop just the bit we need.

Comment: @hippietrail done :)

Comment: There's more detail on the Malagasy deictics [here](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=5i1aMcmLWlMC&pg=PA470&lpg=PA470&dq=malagasy+deixis&source=bl&ots=50GfdlG_e9&sig=NRLPA7F-Ld3ZtlimpRHJmCLBQTk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8NtCT6bJHIWZiAfF1eTrBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=malagasy%20deixis&f=false).

Comment: It only really seems like the Malagasy is a three-way deixis system, with PROX, MED, and DIST. The elaboration here appears to be due to an orthogonal visible evidentiality distinction that happens to be encoded with the same syntactic elements. Evidentiality isn’t usually thought of as deixis, since it has to do with the experience of the origo rather than the spatiotemporal position relative to the origo.

Comment: @JamesC. It's not a three-way system. Those are macro-categories, but as you can clearly see, there are sub-categories for each of them, reaching a total count of seven degrees of distance, which is exactly what I wrote in the answer.

Comment: @Alenanno: There is no explanation of that in the table, and I didn’t see any in a quick scan of the article. What are the sub-categories beneath the ‘PROX’, ‘MED’ and ‘DIST’ columns, and how do those categories constitute deixis?

Comment: @JamesC. Under the PROX category, for the Vis row, we have `etỳ` and `ètu`. I haven't investigated at the time, but do you think they refer to the same thing? I think not. Those are two degrees for the PROX category. The others follow.

Comment: I've added a further reference that confirms the 7-degree deixis.

Comment: @Alenanno There's actually considerable uncertainty about Malagasy: Adelaar and Himmelmann claim a 7-way contrast (but don't provide any edvidence) while others have claimed it to have a 5-way contrast. [Imai (1997)](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=malagasy+deixis&source=web&cd=13&ved=0CEsQFjACOAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.104.5496%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=c26sT8n1Iu-QiAevu8ifAw&usg=AFQjCNFstWH77C0Ya0GpbmysaJMI9KNx2w) gives evidence that Malagasy really has a 3-way system, but accepts that the issue is not settled.

Answer (score 23):

Tlingit has a four-way system of deixis in its demonstratives (which are more like determiners because they cannot encode entities when used alone).

*yá* — proximal: near speaker, usually within reach

*hé* — mesioproximal: near speaker but usually closer to listener than speaker

*wé* — mesiodistal: near listener and out of reach of speaker, or out of reach of both listener and speaker but still easily reachable

*yú* — distal: distant, well beyond the reach of either listener or speaker

To demonstrate:

*yá ax̱ jín* ‘this, my hand’ (speaker gestures to own hand)

*hé i káaxweiyí* ‘this, your coffee’ (speaker gestures to listener’s coffee cup)

*wé x̱ʼaháat* ‘that door’ (speaker gestures to door on other side of the room)

*yú hít* ‘that building’ (speaker gestures to building visible through window)

The most common pair, according to my intuitive experience, are *yá* and *wé* parallelling English ‘this’ and ‘that’. *Yú* is used somewhat less often than *wé*. *Hé* is not used as much as the other three because it is often an irrelevant distinction, but it does occur in a number of conventionalized oppositions such as *yá* ‘right’ vs. *hé* ‘left’, *yá* ‘starboard’ vs. *hé* ‘port’, or *yá* ‘fore’ vs. *hé* ‘back’. All Tlingit speakers I have met demonstrate full competency with the entire system despite any frequency issues, and given its understanding by the semi-speakers and relearners I have talked to, it is probably something acquired fairly early in childhood.

I think the speaker could say *yá i káaxweiyí* only if they touched or were otherwise close to the listener’s coffee cup somehow. If the speaker wanted to differentiate their hands, they could wave their right hand and say *yá ax̱ sheeynax̱.aanáx̱ jín* and then wave their left hand and say *hé ax̱ sʼátnax̱.aanáx̱ jín* ‘this my left hand’.

All of these demonstratives can be used for discourse purposes as well, to locate notional things like propositions, utterances, and situations in positions relative to the spatiotemporal centre of the discourse. Thus one can distance oneself from another’s words by saying *yú hasdu yoo x̱ʼatángi* ‘that (distal) their speech’, or align oneself with another’s words by saying *yá hasdu yoo x̱ʼatángi* ‘this (proximal) their speech’. The subtle differences between these, and indeed the discursive uses of the deixis system in general, have yet to be explored in any sort of detail.

None of this system really has anything to do with visibility or other forms of evidentiality, as has been described in a lot of deictic ‘complex’ systems. It’s instead strictly deixis, encoding the relative distance from the origo. Also note that it has nothing to do with personal exclusivity, since Tlingit has no encoding of inclusive versus exclusive person.

Answer (score 15):

American Sign Language. Spatial diexis is indicated by what looks like a pointing gesture,  (When discussing physically present referents,one just points at them.) for which there is a potentially infinite number of distinctions.

Basic info: [Pronouns in ASL](http://faculty.mdc.edu/psargent/Handouts/Pronouns%20in%20ASL%2007-6.doc) (.doc download)

Details: [The effect of number marking on the use of space in ASL](http://www.gesturestudies.com/Contributions/Cormier/Cormier.html)

Comment: This kind of deixis is the same pragmatic distinction available from pointing in spoken languages. For it to really be a deictic system as conventionally understood there needs to be some sort of categorical distinction between different distances.

Comment: For distances there are (three) but your point holds for compass direction, that are part of the same sign.

Answer (score 10):

According to [John McWhorter](http://www.thegreatcourses.com/tgc/courses/course_detail.aspx?cid=2212), there is a language called Muna (spoken in the Indonesian island of Sulawesi), in which the system of spatial deixis works like this:

> The word *ini* means 'this here,' *itu* means “that
>   there,” *maitu* means “that near him,” *watu* means “that over there
>   by him,” *tatu* means “that up there,” and *nagha* means “that which
>   we can hear but not see”.

Answer (score 9):

Inuktitut is also a language with deixis encoding things such as visible/nonvisible and "up there" as opposed to simply "there, over there".

Comment: It would be great if you could include some examples of them.

Comment: These can be analysed as fusions of deictic+a height demonstrative, but Italian has `quassù` (up here), `quaggiù` (down here), `lassù` (up there), `laggiù` (down there).

Answer (score 8):

Spanish (at least in Mexico) distinguishes two different deixis factors.  I'll show it phonemically instead of orthographically:

```
                   near listener    far from listener
    near speaker        aki              aka
far from speaker        aji              aja
```

So if I'm talking to you about something that's here in the same room as us, I'd say it's `aki`.  It's here where both of us are.

If I'm inviting you to come across the room to sit over here by me, I'd invite you to come `aka`.  This emphasizes that it's over here by me, not "here" where we both are.

If I'm talking about something over near you, I'd say it's `aji`.

If I'm pointing at something far off, something far from both of us, I'd say it's `aja`.

Comment: Where does "ahí" fit in, or isn't it used in Mexico?

Comment: It seems that "allí" and "ahí" have merged in Mexican Spanish.  I've heard native speakers saying they didn't know the difference between the two spellings.  Consider that these are phonemically /aji/ and /ai/, and you can see how they would sound almost exactly the same.

Comment: @Joe Yeísmo takes its toll: /aˈʎi/ is rather further from /ai/. Iberian Spanish doesn’t have so much trouble with those, even in yeístas who say [aˈʝ̞i]

Answer (score 5):

Sinhala, one of the languages spoken in Sri Lanka has a four way deixis system. 
written phonemically - 
*me* = this/these, near the speaker
*oye* = that/those, near the listener
*are* = (distal) visible but far from both speaker and listener
*e* = (distal) not visible to either
Jim Gair has written extensively about it. [This](http://www.lib.kobe-u.ac.jp/repository/81001521.pdf) is an online document I found about it

Answer (score 5):

For Kwakw'ala (Kwakiutl) Boas 1947 grammar describes as deictic system of 3 degrees combined with a distinction visible/invisible

Pronominal demonstratives

*Close to 1st person* visible -**k** invisible **-gaʔ**
*Close to 2nd person* visible **-ux** invisible **-uʔ**
*Away from 1/2nd pers* visible **-iq** invisible **-iʔ**

The visibility distinction may be a typical feature of Nothern Wakashan languages in general (cf Emmon Bach (2006) Paradigm regained: Deixis in Northern Wakashan, SOAS Working Papers in Linguistcs Vol 14:267-281

Answer (score 3):

Some languages [like Japanese](http://books.google.com/books?id=6UAfo7tGROQC&lpg=PT55&ots=wsf4S9qlrd&dq=japanese%20spatial%20deixis&pg=PT55#v=onepage&q=japanese%20spatial%20deixis&f=false) have spatial deixis words that refer to both the speaker and the listener. Sometimes analyzed as proximal, medial and distant, it's more often analyzed as "close to me, the speaker", "close to you, the listener" and "far from the two of us."

Comment: That (ko-, so-, a-) is a three way system. The original question asked about systems that had more than three distinctions.

Answer (score 3):

[Kiranti Languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiranti_languages) are known to exhibit a remarkably unique feature, so-called altitudinal cases. Nouns are always (? I think, it's been a while) marked as being either "above", "below" or "across" (= level). This is tied to both the geographic profile of the region and to the mythological dimensions of verticality.

Answer (score 3):

Portuguese has words sounding like Spanish, but with different meanings:

- Aqui / Cá / Aquém — near from speaker
- Ali / Acolá — medium distance from speaker
- Lá / Além — far from speaker
- Aí — near to listener

Answer (score 2):

[Cebuano](http://learncebuano.com/here-there-over-there/) also has three, from the speaker's point of view:

```
Kini ( ki-ni ) (ni) – this / these
Kana ( ka-na ) (na) – that / those
Kadto ( kad-to ) (to) – that / those over there (far away)
```

Answer (score 1):

The location deixis  in Muna language:

DEIXIS OF LOCATION
demonstrative (pronoun/adjective) Aini (this)  aitu, amaitu,atatu, awatu(that)
Demonstrative (adverbs)          We ini (here)  we itu, we watu (there)