# Are there spoken languages that lack spatial deixis?

Tags: deixis

Just the converse of [this question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/378/are-there-languages-with-other-spatial-deixis-besides-here-there-and-over), really: are there any spoken languages that don't have distinct proximal and distal pronouns (or affixes)?

(I limit it to spoken languages, because [as this answer notes](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/1511/15595), in signed languages one can just point. I suppose one could interpret that as lacking spatial deixis or having an infinite number of distinctions, according to one's preference.)

Comment: One has an infinite number of distinctions in spoken language, too -- intonation varies continuously like music, and interacts with lexical items as well. There are plenty of examples of deictic expressions that accompany gestures, like _yea big_, or _over there_.

Comment: I don't know how you currently classify the use of *dieser* in German, which has lost or is losing distance distinctions that used to be provided with other words, like *jener*.  I think you now use *dieser*  with optional words (loosely the equivalent of "here" and "there") to clarify distance when important.  I think Russia is similar.

Comment: @Vegawatcher Scandinavian has done the same (though using _den_ which was originally distal) – but the optional words that follow, equivalent to _here_ and _there_ are still deictic. Though there are languages that don’t have deictic _pronouns_ (e.g., Irish), I’m not aware of any languages that don’t distinguish between ‘here’ and ‘there’ (or indeed between ‘now’ and ‘then’) in some way.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I've edited the question. Yes I'm sure all language would have lexical items that can be used to indicate the difference.